# flutter migrate objective c project to swift project. Error when use swift plugin

Tags: swift, flutter

If you have an error like

> ***-Swift.m doesn't exist in compile time, or you want to use swift module(plugin) in flutter you must enable swift project.( migrate from objective-c to swift project)

in root folder of project backup ios folder, then delete folder. after that

`flutter create -i swift .`

and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in root folder of project backup ios folder, then delete folder. after that

`flutter create -i swift .`